# Ayuda con mi diseño en Java

Tags: java, diseño, diseño-de-clases

Supongan el siguiente planteamiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hagan de cuenta que es como en el fútbol de la vida real, donde un Equipo juega en una liga dentro del país, sin embargo, el equipo puede cambiar de liga (clase Torneo) por ejemplo si asciende o desciende de división, pero no de país, siempre va a pertenecer al mismo, por esta razón he pensado que para evitar tener que crear 20 objetos del mismo equipo (uno por cada temporada en caso de que existieran 20 temporadas, puesto que cada una posee una variación de equipos) he decido que sea el país quien tenga el control de la lista de equipos, la temporada obviamente también debe poseer una lista de equipos pues que están en esta temporada, el problema es como planteo esta relación en programación, si hago por ejemplo en la clase Temporada

```
private ArrayList<Equipo> equiposQueJueganEstaTemporda;
```

¿se estarán copiando en memoria la X cantidad de equipos que posee cada temporada las N temporadas que existan o se estará almacenando una referencia a la lista de Equipos que posee la clase Pais? esto dado que una referencia "debe" ocupar menos espacio en memoria que un Equipo (como por ejemplo lo que sucede con apuntadores en c/c++), o en este caso es mejor tener algo asi

```
private ArrayList<String> nombresEquiposQueJueganEstaTemporda;
```

donde el string representa el nombre de cada equipo (el cual es irrepetible) y el cual representaria aquella "referencia" al arrayList que posee la clase Pais esto para evitar tener que crear una copia completa del objeto Equipo varias veces

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cuál es tu duda, pero creo que estás entendiendo mal el asunto. ¿Tú piensas que cada vez que haya un partido vas a tener que crear una instancia de la clase `Temporada`? ¿Por qué crees que haya que hacer eso? Algo que ayuda a comprender y diseñar tu modelo de datos es el lugar donde vas a almacenar los datos. En una BD por ejemplo tendrías una tabla `temporada` y otra `temporada_equipo` donde reflejarías qué equipos juegan en qué temporada. La lista de equipos como ves no estaría en la tabla `temporada` sino en una tabla auxiliar que gestiona la relación.

Comment: Me refiero a que cada Temporada trae equipos Diferentes pero dentro de un mismo país y por eso es que País es quien posee el Arraylist de equipos, básicamente al final la duda radica en como los arraylist funcionan, es decir, si al final un arraylist posee un objeto Equipo o algo asi como una referencia a un Objeto Equipo, esto por tema de utilizar la menor cantidad de recursos

Comment: Es que no, con todo respeto, asignar a la clase `Pais` un arraylist de equipos es un disparate, es irracional. Para mi una de las mayores ventajas de la POO es que te ayuda a pensar el programa basándote en la realidad misma y no en algo abstracto. Hay que preguntarse: ¿una lista de equipos es una *propiedad*  de todo `Pais`? o, pensado de otro modo, ¿qué es lo propiamente **intrínseco** de un `Pais`? Con que en el mundo entero haya un `Pais` que no tenga un equipo ya no puedes meter una lista de equipos en esa clase. Una lista de equipos es algo más bien intrínseco de  `Torneo` o de `Liga`.